# Tracking "Define" events on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, event-handling

Hi i'm creating an iOS 7 app and would like "watch" for user selections and then trigger some event.

It's a mimic of the dictionary app that comes with iOS 7, that you can select a word and it defines it for you, but in this case other action will be taken when a word is selected (after it's selected).

Where can i find documentation on this subject? i have tried searching on google but found nothing...

Thanks, any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: give some code or facing issue

Comment: what i need is a pointer of where can i start. Haven't wrote anything on the subject still.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotificationCenter. Post a notification when user selects a word, then having other objects to observe for that specific notification and take your actions

Comment: i need the user to be abble to select a word anywhere, not just inside tbe app. Are all selections automatically posted to the notification center?

Comment: You dont have access to the system functionality. You need a jailbroken device to do that

Comment: There are multiple apps on the app store that provide this functionality. There must be a way